# How is the time complexity of the following function O(n³)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I was going through the Algorithm lecture series of Stanford University on Coursera by Tim Roughgarden. There, he gave a multiple choice question to find the running time complexity of a function, which is given below in the image.

[image]

In this question, the last three options are correct. I understand how the first two options for Ω (Omega) and Θ (Theta) are correct just by looking at the function, but I am unable to grasp how the last option is correct because as far as I can tell, the running time complexity should be O(n<sup>2</sup>) instead of O(n<sup>3</sup>).

Can anyone please explain where I am wrong?

Comment: What's the definition of big-O you're using? If you can't recall the definition without looking it up, how did you get the answer you got?

Comment: In this case these three notations mean different things. Big-Omega `O(n)` is the best case scenario, then the next, Big-Theta `O(n^2)` is the average case scenario, and last, Big-oh `O(n^3)` is the worst case scenario. That is why there are all true. As this function can at most be `O(n^3)` and at least `O(n)` for all inputs.

Comment: Your question seems better suited for [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com). You can also use LaTeX there, AFAIK, so all the math will get a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be mathematically precise, big O, big Omega, etc are all sets, not functions.  So, when we say T(n) = O(n^3), we really mean that T(n) is in the set O(n^3).  But since it is not easy to typeset the "in the set" notation, we usually just end up writing that T(n) = O(n^3).  Hence, it cause a bit of confusion, but basically O(n^3) is simply the set of functions that do not grow faster than n^3.  And of course, the given T(n) does not grow faster than n^3, so T(n) is in the set O(n^3).

And similarly, T(n) is in the sets O(n^4), O(n^5), O(n^3 log n), O(n^127), O(n^n^n), etc.

So, if you had a fifth option in the question: T(n) = O(n^2), that would be true as well.

Comment: please explain why the answer is not O(n^2). I'm unable to understand it.

Comment: @DG4 The answer is O(n^2) and O(n^3) and O(n^4)... etc.  Each subsequent set is bigger than the previous set, so all of those are correct answers.  That is just a Math way of saying that the given function does not grow faster than n^2, it also does not grow faster than n^3, it also does not grow faster than n^4.... etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

`O(n^2)` is a subset of `O(n^3)`. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) is good for this.

In fact `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` if `lim |f(x)|/g(x)` is less then infinity (n goes to infinity). Here it would be

```
O(1/2*n^2+3n) is in O(n^3) 
<=> lim |(1/2*n^2+3n)| / n^3
<=> lim |(n*[n/2 + 3])| / n^3
<=> lim |(n/2 + 3)| / n^2 < infinty

for n to infinity n^2 is allways greater then n/2 so for positiv n this goes against 0
```

Another way to proof this is: Can you find a `k` and a `c` (both positiv) so that `f(n)` is always smaller then  `k*g(n) + c` (not for all `n` - It is enough if this is true for one `n0` and all numbers greater then `n0`). Here you can choose `k=1` and `c=0` because as mentioned before `n^2` is always smaller then `n^3` for positive `n`.

[Here](https://aaronbloomfield.github.io/pdr/slides/images/04-arrays-bigoh/omega-diagram-1.png) is a nice picture of the O notation as a Veen-Diagram.

Comment: according to your explanation, I understood that this last line
` lim |(1/2n + 3) / n^2|` will be less than infinity. But is I take g(x) as n^2. Then, it will be ` lim |(1/2*n^2+3n) / n^2|` and that too will be less than infinity. Now, where I am wrong?

Comment: Yes you are right the function is also in `O(n^2)`. `O(n^3)` also contains all functions from `O(n^2)` so this is okay. In generell `O(n^x)` contains all functions where the gratetest polynom is `O(n^x)` or smaller then `x`.

Comment: But the same thing will happen in O(n^4) also, so why don't we take it?

Comment: Yes of course. The `O` notation is not a sharp boundary (where we are most interested in). In fact it is a upper limit in worst case. If we want a sharp boundary we have to use the `Theta` notation which is the third option in the question. Please also see the picture in my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I recommend not to think about asympotic bounds as a part of computer science; it's a mathematical tool. Do not associate "Big O" strictly with "worst case" or such. Big O gives an *asymptotic upper bound*. That's it. It happens to be useful in computer science to describe the worst case running time of an algorithm, but it's math, not computer science that describes how it works.
But that's just my opinion, mind you.

---

Take this definition for Big O notation. (This is the formal definition I've learnt first.)
From [*Introduction to Algorithms 3<sup>rd</sup> Edition*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms) (I'm still learning about algorithms myself through that book), page 47:

> For a given function g(n), we denote by O(g(n)) [...]  the set of
>   functions
>
> O(g(n)) = { f(n) : there exist positive constants c and n<sub>0</sub>
>   such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub> }.

Observe Big O notation denotes a *set* and as such, it can be part of a *superset* and it can be a superset to other *subsets*. Writing "n = O(n)" is just a formally incorrect way of saying that the function f(n) = n is a member of the set O(n) (n ∈ O(n)).

Abusing Big O notation (i.e., placing it in equations) like this enables us to use it in equations and to write stuff like T(n) = 1/2n + O(n), which basically means that T(n) equals 1/2n plus *some function* for which the definition of Big O notation given above holds true.

So, you wonder why something like n<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>3</sup>)? Let's show through our formal definition:

g(n) = n<sup>3</sup>
f(n) = n<sup>2</sup>

0 ≤ n<sup>2</sup> ≤ cn<sup>3</sup> for all n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>

Intuitively, we can easily see that there must be some c and n<sub>0</sub> (actually, c ≥ 1 and n<sub>0</sub> = 0) for this inequality to be true because a cubic function grows asymptotically faster than a quadratic one.

Do the same for g(n) = n<sup>2</sup> and you'll see that n<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>2</sup>) as well (for c ≥ 1 and n<sub>0</sub> = 0).

So, n<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>3</sup>) **and** n<sup>2</sup> = O(n<sup>2</sup>)? This is possible because O(n<sup>3</sup>) and O(n<sup>2</sup>) are not disjoint; O(n<sup>2</sup>) is a subset of O(n<sup>3</sup>) because every quadratic function can be bounded from above by a cubic function.

As you see, asympotic bounds need not be *tight*; n = O(n<sup>65536</sup>) is *true*. However, tight bounds are obviously preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you can prove that it's `O(n^2)` (which you have to in order to prove it's `Big Theta(n^2)`. Don't do it just by "looking at it", do the math.), then replace all occurrences of `n^2` with `n^3` in the proof.

Is it still still correct?

Remember that Big-oh is an upper bound.

Comment: @IVIad, can you show that how to prove that mathematically? Because I am confused as how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`T(n) = O(n^2) <=>` there exists constants `c > 0, n0 >= 0` s.t. `T(n) <= c.n^2` for all `n >= n0`.

Now,   `c.n^2 <= c.n^3` for all `n > 1` (an identity)

`=>     T(n) <= c.n^2 <= c.n^3` for all `n >= n1 = max(n0, 1)`

`=>`     there exists constants `c > 0, n1 = max(n0, 1)`, s.t.  `T(n) <= c.n^3`

```
=>     T(n) = O(n^3)
```

In fact we can show that `T(n)=O(n^2) => T(n)=O(n^k)` for all `n>=2` (e.g. use induction).